# Zoom in on point in canvas, where everything is based off of a certain point

Tags: java, android, canvas

Alright, bit of a strange one. I'll do my best to explain.
I'm building a game on Android (Java). And I'm just working out the views first. The first thing I'm working on is a solar system view (top down, 2d, no tilt). I've got all the planets and the star displaying properly, and in proportion. I can pan, and zoom. The only issue is, the way I've set up all the circles to draw, they're all based on one point (where the star is), and when I 'zoom'/'pan' I'm not actually zooming/panning. For the pan, I'm just moving the point where everything revolves, and for the zoom, I'm not scaling the whole canvas (tried that, didn't work out) I'm adjusting the size of the elements I'm drawing, in accordance with the zoom.

So I've got a 'star' that starts out in the middle of the screen, the point is called orbitLocation.
And a zoom variable that starts at `1f`.
The star is drawn very simply - `canvas.drawCircle((float)orbitLocation.x, (float)orbitLocation.y, this.radius * zoom, this.paint);`

Each of the planets are positioned like so:
`canvas.drawCircle(getPlanetX(angle, orbitLocation, zoom), getPlanetY(angle, orbitLocation, zoom), this.radius * zoom, this.paint);`

`getPlanetX` and `getPlanetY` look like this:

```
private float getPlanetX(double angle, Point orbitingPoint, float zoom) {
        return orbitingPoint.x + (this.distance * Constants.AU * zoom) * (float)Math.sin(angle);
    }

    private float getPlanetY(double angle, Point orbitingPoint, float zoom) {
        return orbitingPoint.y + (this.distance * Constants.AU * zoom) * (float)Math.cos(angle);
    }
```

`Constants.AU` is a constant int `11507` in place for Astronomical Unit - for proper scaling.

Now the problem I'm having with zoom, is if I pan, and then zoom, the whole thing scales from the orbitLocation, disregarding where I'm trying to zoom in on, so whatever was right in the middle of my screen, quickly gets thrown way off screen.

Desired outcome. Have whatever is in the center of the screen (or between fingers in pinch, either way), stay in the center of the screen, and the orbit point adjust itself in accordance.

Here's the relevant part of my touch event:

```
if (touchCount == 2) { // if pinch
                    if (startZoomTouchPoint != null) {
                        float newDistance = getDistance(event, 0, 1);
                        float distanceDifference = (startZoomDistance - newDistance);
                        zoom -= distanceDifference * (zoom / 100);
                        if (zoom < MIN_ZOOM) {
                            zoom = MIN_ZOOM;
                        }

//                        Point zoomCenter = getZoomCenter(event);
//                        int yOrbitOffset = orbitLocation.y - zoomCenter.y;
//                        int xOrbitOffset = orbitLocation.x - zoomCenter.x;
//                        orbitLocation.x += xOrbitOffset + Constants.AU * zoom;
//                        orbitLocation.y += yOrbitOffset + Constants.AU * zoom;

                        startZoomDistance = newDistance;
                        updateStartZoomTouchPoint(event);
                    }
                }
```

Those commented lines in the middle are my latest attempt to achieve my goal.

Every time I try, I either move the `orbitLocation` way too much, or not enough, or it moves around weirdly.

`getZoomCenter` literally just gets the point between the 2 fingers. We can just use the center of the screen if that's easier.

Alright, that's all I've got. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following code snippet

```
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float zoom = 1.f;

public MyCustomView(Context mContext){
    ...
    // View code goes here
    ...
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new 
    ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(zoom, zoom);
    ...
    // onDraw() code goes here
    ...
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener
    extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        zoom = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to scale the canvas based on the scale value obtained from the touch event. You can do that by

1. Save the canvas
2. Scale the canvas
3. Draw what you were drawing
4. Restore the canvas

and you can set the zoom on the response of scale gesture detector. Call invalidate afterwards.

For more information visit https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale